# how to avoid the x terminal forwarding

Tags: macos, ssh, git, port-forwarding, x11-forwarding

I use our remote server along with a team. apparently they made all the apps automatically do x forwarding. I know this b/c now if i simply want to run a git command 
`git pull` I get this error:

```
(gnome-ssh-askpass:6041): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

doing some research i realized this is an x forwarding issue.

The thing is i *don't* want to this x-forwarding.

**what i tried**

i tried shutting off this x forwarding server by running `ps aux | grep -nri x11` and killing all the processes that look like they're x forwarding? didn't work.

i tried connecting to the remote server using the `ssh -x` option which according to the ssh manual `Disables X11 forwarding.`:

```
sshpass -p %password% ssh -x -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@port
```

didn't work either.. ideas?

Comment: I think you’re misunderstanding something. Unless the clients requests X11 forwarding, it isn’t active. The server has no say in this, apart from being able to deny the request for forwarding. What you’re facing is simply an inappropriate “askpass” command.

Comment: This seems to be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348688/using-the-git-client-on-a-headless-linux-server ;)